# Orthogonal complement of S and related question

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let V be a real vector space with a topology induced from an inner product. 
Let S be a subset.
Can we say either of the following ?

1. closure(S) = perp(perp(S)) ,   [where perp(X) =  orthogonal complement of X]
2. closure(span(S)) = perp(perp(S))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is false: the orthogonal complement $S^\perp=\{x\mid\forall s\in S: x\perp s\}$ of any set $S$ is always a closed subspace, whereas the closure need not be a subspace.
2. is true: prove $S^\perp =\overline{\mathrm{span}(S)}^\perp$, and apply $U^{\perp\perp} =U$ for a closed subspace $U$.

Comment: what do you mean the closure need not be?
The closure is by definition closed isn't it?

Comment: Need not be a subspace. For example, a closed ball is closed but not a subspace. Its perp is $\{0\}$.